# Clicking the Next button in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I am crawling a page using Selenium in Python. Here I need to click on the next button(div) but I get error:

elemnt :

`<div class=""><div class="pagination-next" id="pager_next_page_id"><span class="has-text-weight-bold text-size-12-n space-4-left-n is-hidden-mobile-small">بعدی</span><span class="mi-left text-size-8-n"></span></div></div>`

Also, the value of is_display is False, the value of is_enabled is True, and is_selected is False.

code :

`next_btn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pager_next_page_id').click()`

error :

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.70)
```

Comment: Can you confirm the page URL?

Comment: This page will be displayed after login, so it is not possible to access that page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to click by javascript:

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pager_next_page_id'))`

Plus, Make sure the element is unique.